# How to correct the history record

Tags: database, oracle

I want to update history data in oracle database.

emp table

```
ID      SALE_COM    UPDATEDATE              SALES_DT
4173    40          09-APR-2016 20:04:07    null
4173    40          20-SEP-2016 20:04:11    null
4173    30          06-OCT-2016 20:04:07    null
4173    30          14-OCT-2016 20:04:07    null
4173    30          26-MAR-2017 20:50:41    null
```

emp_hist

```
EMP_ID  FIN_Y_ID    PRD_SEQ  FIELD_VALUE    FIN_DATE
2167    13          4        30             28/09/14 0:00
```

OUTPUT

```
4173    30  06-OCT-2016 20:04:07    28/09/14 0:00
```

Comment: 1. emp table
 ID  SALE_COM UPDATEDATE SALES_DT
4173 40   09-APR-2016 20:04:07     null
4173 40   20-SEP-2016 20:04:11    null
4173 30   06-OCT-2016 20:04:07    null
4173 30   14-OCT-2016 20:04:07    null
4173 30   26-MAR-2017 20:50:41   null

2. emp_hist  
EMP_ID FIN_Y_ID PRD_SEQ FIELD_VALUE .  FIN_DATE
2167 13     4                      30            28/09/14 0:00

output 
ID      SALE_COM    UPDATEDATE               SALES_DT
4173     30               06-OCT-2016 20:04:07    28/09/14 0:00

Comment: Please don't place table data or code in a comment. It's completely unusable. Please also explain how and why you came up with this OUTPUT, it's not at all clear how these two tables relate to each other since the two employee_ids are different and your output lacks column headers.

Comment: Thank Nevill emp_hist table empid=4173

Comment: Actually as per requirement when ever my SALE_COM value will change the update the null value to findate.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "requirement" is though. This is still very unclear how you start with these two tables and end up with that output. I'm guessing it's just a simple inner join, but who knows... Please "Edit" your question and include the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to answer this without the problem being more clearly defined, but here's my interpretation:

1. There are two tables: emp and emp_hist
2. The 2167 shown in emp_hist in the original post is incorrect and should actually be 4173
3. When EMP.SALES_COM is updated, you want to update EMP.SALES_DT from the value of EMP_HIST.FIN_DATE where EMP.ID = EMP_HIST.EMP_ID

Assuming EMP_HIST.EMP_ID is unique, you could create a trigger on EMP that does #3 above:

```
SQL> SELECT id, sale_com, TO_CHAR(updatedate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') updatedate,
  2          TO_CHAR(sales_dt, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') sales_dt
  3    FROM emp;

        ID   SALE_COM UPDATEDATE                    SALES_DT      
---------- ---------- ----------------------------- --------------
      4173         40 09-APR-2016 20:04:07                        
      4173         40 20-SEP-2016 20:04:11                        
      4173         30 06-OCT-2016 20:04:07                        
      4173         30 14-OCT-2016 20:04:07                        
      4173         30 26-MAR-2017 20:50:41                        

SQL> SELECT emp_id, FIN_Y_ID, PRD_SEQ, FIELD_VALUE, TO_CHAR(FIN_DATE, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI') fin_date
  2    FROM emp_hist;

    EMP_ID   FIN_Y_ID    PRD_SEQ FIELD_VALUE FIN_DATE      
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------------
      4173         13          4          30 14/09/28 00:00

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_upd_sale_com BEFORE UPDATE ON emp FOR EACH ROW
  2  BEGIN
  3    SELECT fin_date
  4      INTO  :new.sales_dt
  5      FROM emp_hist
  6      WHERE emp_id = :old.id;
  7  END;

Trigger EMP_UPD_SALE_COM compiled

SQL> UPDATE emp SET sale_com = 30
  2    WHERE id = 4173 AND updatedate = TO_DATE('06-OCT-2016 20:04:07', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

1 row updated.

SQL> SELECT id, sale_com, TO_CHAR(updatedate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') updatedate,
  2         TO_CHAR(sales_dt, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') sales_dt
  3    FROM emp;

        ID   SALE_COM UPDATEDATE                    SALES_DT      
---------- ---------- ----------------------------- --------------
      4173         40 09-APR-2016 20:04:07                        
      4173         40 20-SEP-2016 20:04:11                        
      4173         30 06-OCT-2016 20:04:07          28/09/14 00:00 <<<< Updated row
      4173         30 14-OCT-2016 20:04:07                        
      4173         30 26-MAR-2017 20:50:41
```